# ¿Cómo puedo registrar el "siguiente" id con llave primaria de tipo string?

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando con MySql. Intento pasar una consulta de SQL Server a MySql. Tengo una tabla `Empleado`

```
CREATE TABLE Empleado
(
  Id VARCHAR(4),
  Nombre VARCHAR(100)   
)
```

Intento crear el `Id` con una sentencia MySql

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(ISNULL(MAX(Id) + 1, 1), 4), ' ', '0') FROM empleado
```

Esta consulta en SQL Server hace lo siguiente: `0001`, `0002`, `0003`, etc. La necesito en MySql.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de lo que tiene que hacer esa función en sql para que la podamos traducir a mysql.

Comment: @Error404 esa sentencia hace lo siguiente `0001`, `0002`, `0003`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo semejante en MySQL con:

```
SELECT LPAD( IFNULL( MAX( Id ) + 1, 1 ) , 4,  '0' ) 
FROM empleado
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes usar, teniendo en cuenta que tienes almacenados los valores `1`, `2` y `3` en tu base de datos puedes utilizar la función [LPAD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad).

```
SELECT LPAD(Id,4,'0') FROM empleado
```

en el cual el primer parámetro que le pasas a la función es el nombre de la columna, el segundo parámetro es la cantidad de caracteres que va a tener la salida y el tercer parámetro el string que se va a introducir al principio del String hasta completar la cantidad de números de caracteres introducidos.